# "Removable Storage Access" Group Policy and RSAT

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy, windows

I've seen that there is a capability with Group Policy to prevent users from writing to USB drives.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/08/25/removable-storage-group-policy-and-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista.aspx

I'd like to do this.  I thought that I'd be able to see this on my machine with Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) installed, but that Group Policy is not appearing under *User Configuration\Policies\System\Removable Storage Access*.

Do I need to upgrade the functional level of our domain from our current Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 in order to do this?  It seems like using a machine with RSAT installed, I'm able to see all Windows 2008 Group Policy settings.

Anywho, any help with this would be awesome.

P.S. We are transition our forest to 2008, but that is going to take a little while and we need to implement this policy sooner.
[image: Here is what Group Policy Management Editor looks like]

Comment: Can you clarify your question so that we are sure what platform you are on.  I am assuming it's Windows Server 2003 but I don't want to assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had setup the [central store](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929841) previously, but I didn't have all of the [administrative templates for Windows 2008 R2/Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6243) there.